# Weird plot of LASSO regression, what's the problem and how to fix it?

Tags: r

I did LASSO regression for my data.

However, the two plots (coefficients plot and cross validation plot) seemed not very well.

The problem with the coefficients plot is: some coefficients grow and then drop, as the lambda changes. In published papers, the coefficients drop as the lambda changes. They don't grow.

[coefficients plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmNEX.jpg)

The problem with the cross validation plot is: a part of the red line is not continuous with others.

[cross validation plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClE9L.png)

My data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/onkaparinga/default/main/train3.csv

My code:

```
library(readr)
library(glmnet)

train3 <- read_csv('train3.csv')

x <- as.matrix(train3[,-1])
y <- train3$CustomLabel
cvlasso <- cv.glmnet(x,y,alpha = 1,family = 'binomial')
plot(cvlasso)
plot(cvlasso$glmnet.fit)
```

---

Before LASSO regression, I actually did correlation analysis to remove variables that are highly correlated(>0.9) with others.

```
#read dataset
train2 <- read_csv('train2.csv')

#get non-normalized varibles
non_norm_vars <- train2 %>% 
  summarise(across(1:(ncol(train2)-1),~shapiro.test(.x)$p.value)) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  filter(V1<0.05) %>% 
  rownames()

#get normalized varibles
norm_vars <- colnames(train2)[!colnames(train2) %in% non_norm_vars] %>% 
  head(-1)

#rearrange the dataset 'train2',put normalized variable in the front, so convinient for replace.
df_nonnorm <- train2[,non_norm_vars]
df_norm <- train2[,norm_vars]
train3 <- bind_cols(df_norm,df_nonnorm)

#calculate coefficient for normalized and overall varibales
cor_norm <- cor(df_norm,method = 'pearson')
cor_all <- cor(train3,method = 'spearman')
#replace the coefficient by normalized variable's
num_norm <- dim(cor_norm)[1]
cor_all[1:num_norm,1:num_norm] <- cor_norm


#sum how many 'high coefficients' (>0.9) each variable has, and rearrange by descendant.
var_seq <- cor_all %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  reframe(across(everything(),~sum(abs(.x)>0.9))) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  arrange(desc(V1)) %>% 
  rownames()
#slice_seq: index of var_seq in colnames(cor_all)
slice_seq <- match(var_seq,colnames(cor_all))
#make a new matrix, most 'high coefficients' variable in the front, least in the end.
cor_all <- cor_all %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(all_of(var_seq)) %>% 
  slice(slice_seq) %>% 
  as.matrix()
rownames(cor_all) <- colnames(cor_all)

#set to triangle matrix
cor_all[upper.tri(cor_all)] <- 0
diag(cor_all) <- 0

#keep variables that has 0 'high coefficients'
cor_vars <- cor_all %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(),~any(abs(.x)>0.9))) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  filter(V1 == F) %>% 
  rownames()
#train3 got
train3 <- train2 %>% 
  select(CustomLabel, all_of(cor_vars))
```

hope my poor English did not confuse you ...

train2: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/onkaparinga/default/main/train2.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data set `train3` has substantial collinearity, i. e. 4244 bivariate combinations have an r² of at least .9:

```
corr_mat <- cor(train3[-1])

expand.grid(A = dimnames(corr_mat)[[1]],
            B = dimnames(corr_mat)[[2]]
            ) |>
  cbind(r2 = as.vector(corr_mat)^2) |>
  as_tibble() |>
  filter(as.vector(upper.tri(corr_mat)),
         r2 > .9,
         r2 < 1
         ) |> 
  print(n = 3)
```

```
# A tibble: 4,244 x 3
  A     B        r2
  <fct> <fct> <dbl>
1 A693  A1228 0.996
2 A693  A1597 0.988
3 A1228 A1597 0.992
# i 4,241 more rows
```

Moreover, 31 of your features have at least 3 extreme outliers off the mean by four [*sic*] standard deviations or more:

```
train3 |>
summarise(across(where(is.numeric), 
                 ~ sum(abs(mean(.x) - .x) > 4 * sd(.x))
                 )
          ) |> t() |> 
  as.data.frame() |>
  filter(V1 > 3) |>
  nrow()

## + [1] 31
```

Both multicollinearity and outliers can severely [topple your regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lasso+bootstrap+instability).
It would thus be good to put a dimensionality reduction and some outlier management up front of your modelling chain.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually did correlation analysis and removed the variables that has a coefficient > 0.9. I will put how I did it in my main question.

Comment: You're welcome! If it worked for you, please mark your question as closed by flagging the answer as "accepted".

Comment: Many thanks! Now it seems my question turned to how to remove the collinear variables, since I actually DID the ```cor()``` function before LASSO...You code showed great reference, would it be possible to continue with you code to reduce the collinear ones?

Comment: My pleasure. But that'd deserve a separate question though. If you expect to do a lot of modelling, packages {caret} or {tidymodels} might be worth a look early on: https://towardsdatascience.com/caret-vs-tidymodels-create-complete-reusable-machine-learning-workflows-5c50a7befd2d E. g. with {tidymodels}, bundling collinear variables to a feature is a one-liner : https://www.tmwr.org/dimensionality.html#principal-component-analysis